# Как вывести весь датафрейм в jupyter nootebok

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

Например если написать `df`, то выведутся первые и последние строки датафрейма.
Если написать `df_result.tail(50)`, то выведутся последние 50 строк.
А как вывести вообще все строки до единой?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30691921/8324991) есть ответ. Просто надо снять ограничения на количество отображаемых строк (тут заодно и для столбцов эта опция выставляется):

```
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None):  # more options can be specified also
    print(df)
```

В данном примере эти опции выставляются для разового использования и потом возвращаются обратно. Если хотите совсем отменить ограничения, то сделайте так:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
```